# Pasted commands do not appear in history

Tags: history, copy

when I use copy and paste to run a command, and later I want to run the command again it doesn't appear in history.

Sometimes if I paste and then change some of the arguments the command does appear in the history.

How can I make sure that all the commands that I run appear in history?

Comment: If you paste a command with a leading space, they do not appear in history. Check this.

Comment: To change this behavior, check the manpage and look for HISTCONTROL.  For exmaple, `export HISTCONTROL=""` in .bashrc would do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you paste a command with a leading space, they do not appear in history. Such a thing can easily happen if you copy and paste commands (eg. from websites or documents)

Comment: Exactly what I just wanted to type... You're too fast! ;)

Comment: @ByteCommander sorry, you need answers, I know. =\

Comment: @user844541: If you like the answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask